# Choose content element with typoscript in TYPO3 LTS 8.7

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I try actually to render/display a content element in the footer of the template whitch will be the same for every site.

What I tried:

I integrated the lib.footer.ts file in the setup. But also if I put it directly into the setup it will show nothing at all.

**File setup.ts:**

```
footerSocial < lib.footer.social
```

**File lib.footer.ts**

```
lib.footer.social = RECORDS 
lib.footer.social {
   tables = tt_content
   source = 9
   dontCheckPid = 1
}
```

**File template.ts:**

```
{footerSocial -> f:format.raw()}
```

But it doesnt work under TYPO3 8.7 LTS. I have no idea. I did that in many cases but only in TYPO3 6.2 and TYPO3 7.6. Is there another syntax?

I didn't get the trick yet. :(

Thanks for your help!

************** UPDATE **************

What I have new 'til now:

**File lib.footer.ts**

```
lib.footer.social = CONTENT
lib.footer.social {
tables = tt_content
source = 9
dontCheckPid = 1
}
```

Now the CEs will be displayed BUT now ALL CEs of this site will be rendered there.

Any Ideas?

BR
Chris

Comment: footerSocial is a variable in your FLUIDTEMPLATE object?

Have you tried with <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.footer.social" /> ?

Comment: yes i tried it, but there is still the same problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the template-, partial- and layout-paths?
In some cases I had the same problem. Once it works after I declared:

```
templateRootPaths {                                                 
     0 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Templates/      
     10 = fileadmin/Templates/Templates/                            
}                                                                   
partialRootPaths {                                                  
    0 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Partials/        
    10 = fileadmin/Templates/Partials/                              
}                                                                   
layoutRootPaths {                                                   
    0 = EXT:fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/Layouts/         
    10 = fileadmin/Templates/Layouts/                               
}
```

???

Comment: No i didn't yet. because 'til now i hadn't to do that. but I'll try it and come back to you. thx

Comment: I've tested it with other names. Nothing different.

Answer (score 0):

did you declare your typoscript objects in the order you gave here?
then your first assignement copies nothing.

Have you declared `footerSocial` as TS object?
then the access `{footerSocial -> f:format.raw()}` acesses nothing.
You need to declare the variable like

```
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        :
        variables {
            footerSocial < lib.footer.social
            :
        }
    }
}
```

do your CE 9 render correctly?
try to insert the rendering immediatly:

```
page.999 < lib.footer.social
```

or you may vary the displayed CE with another CE type or with another declaration for `lib.footer.social` like:

```
lib.footer.social = TEXT
lib.footer.social.value = <h1>I'm here!</h1>
```

Comment: yes I tried it already with a TEXT. Works perfectly! That's the point. But i have a new behaviour. Please check my updated quesiton. thanks for your help.

Comment: btw: yes the CEs will be rendered correctly. But the problem - as updated above - is, that all CEs will be rendered there. :( Not only ID 9)